# How to remove nested UL element but keep child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wish to remove the `<ul>` tags for a nested list and then add its child `<li>` elements to the parent `<ul>` element. For example :

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <ul>
        <li>Item 2</li>
    </ul>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Should become :

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

I am new to jQuery and what I have created so far is not working and I am not sure why:

```
 $content.find('ul').each(function() {
if ($(this).parent().is('li')) {
  var elements = $(this).children().detach();
  var closest = $(this).closest('li');
  $(this).remove();
  elements.appendTo(closest);
}
}
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Your original list HTML is invalid and your jQuery seems to have some issues with brackets.

Comment: I have not added <html> and a <body> tags because they are not relevant. Also I hand typed the jQuery on here which is why i missed a bracket, now corrected.

Comment: @user1570775 They're not talking about the lack of `<html>` and `<body>` tags, they're talking about the fact that `<ul>` elements can't be immediate children of `<ul>` elements; it should be `<ul>...<li><ul><li>...</li></ul></li>...</ul>`

Comment: By invalid HTML I meant that the code you posted was invalid, not that it was missing a full page HTML example. You can't have a `<ul>` as a direct child of another `<ul>`.

Comment: If you create an indented list in Word2003 and then copy/paste it into tinyMCE, that is how it is represented.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use [.unwrap()](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qKKbW/) or [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qKKbW/1)

```
$('ul > ul > li').unwrap('ul');
```

Comment: That works for the example given but its not consistent how many levels down this problem may occur, sorry I should have been clearer in my description.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
var elements = [];
$('ul.outer li').each(function(){
    elements.push(this); 
});
$('ul.outer').html('');
for(x in elements){
    $('ul.outer').append($(elements[x])[0].outerHTML);
}
```

if you need it to work for .. multiple levels deep .. for example

```
<ul class="outer">
<li>Item 1</li>
<ul>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <ul>
        <li>Item 2</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
<li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: There are no classes on any of the ul elements